# How to understand Angular service call?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, angular6

I am trying to make a http call to get some data from remote server in Angular. I am using Angular 6. Here I am able to get list of record with both method (`getEmploy, getEmploy1`) mentioned below.

The issue is that I don't understand what is difference between both way of calling API URL and which method should I use.

SERVICE.ts:

```
<pre>
    getEmploy() : Observable<IEmployee[]>
    {
       return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url);
    }

     getEmploy1() 
     {
         return this.http.get(this._url);
     }

</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In approach 1, you are adding a type

> IEmployee

to the the data that you are receiving from API, so you are saying that the data is of type IEmployee. This is what you should do if you really want to take advantage of TypeScript.

In Approach 2, the type of the data becomes

> any

.. and since it is any.. you really don't get the benefits of typing.

Comment: thanks for replying, i am getting same result from both method then why should i use first method which is very confusing to me. 

i want to understand if there are something which i am missing if i use approach 2.

Comment: if you use approach 2, it will work.. but the point is since you are using TypeScript provide a type to your data...